# WAMP php openssl extension activated but not loaded

Tags: apache-http-server, php, openssl, wamp

I've installed WAMP3 and everything finally went well. However, I am now encountering a problem where a PHP extension seems **activated** but **not loaded**.

- WAMP 32bit on 64bit system (had to for MSSQL support)
- Apache 2.4.17
- PHP 5.6.15
- MySQL 5.7.9 (but most likely irrelevant)

I have installed OpenSSL 1.0.2g from [Shining Light Productions](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) and copied libeay32.dll, ssleay32.dll and openssl.exe to the apache bin folder.

Windows ENV path points to the right folders and config files.

Obviously, the php.ini has uncommented lines for php_openssl.dll (and yes, that includes the php.ini file apache uses, not just the CLI file). WAMP also shows the extension as **activated**.

In phpinfo, there is no openssl or SSL section showing. However, "OpenSSL/1.0.2g" appears under:

- Apache Version
- SERVER_SIGNATURE
- SERVER_SOFTWARE
- SSL Version

OPENSSL config file path is correct.

Using var_dump(extension_loaded('openssl')); in a script outputs:

```
boolean false
```

Any ideas why the extension could be activated but not loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so I guess this was a conflict with PHP 5.6.15's original openssl DLL and the new OpenSSL files.

The solution was to grap the latest [PHP for Windows](http://windows.php.net/download/) for PHP 5.6, unzip the file and replace the DLL in /php5.6.15/ext by the one freshly downloaded.

So if you need OpenSSL to work with WAMP3, you need to get the latest OpenSSL files from SLP as mentioned in the question, and then replace the DLL as well.

Comment: No you dont. It works fine out of the box. It sounds like you have something in you PATH that you should not have. To run WAMPServer there should be NOTHING in the PATH pointing to ANYTHING in the `\wamp\.....` folder structure at all. In fact if there is something on the PATH that is anything to do with PHP or APACHE or MYSQL it will cause problems very simialiar to the ones you describe.

Comment: Also if you do want to replace the `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` you should place them in the `\wamp\bin\php\php{version}` folder as a restart of WAMPServer will cause the SYMLINKS in the `\wamp\bin\apache\apache{version}\bin` folder to be rebuilt to point to these files among others in the PHP folder.

Comment: So copying the `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` to the Apache folder would have been instantly overwritten when you started WAMPServer, the other reason your attempt at upgrading these was always failing